# React Native - sometimes app freezes when opened from background

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, background, freeze

Recently I noticed some strange bug in my IOS app (on Android I did not see that problem so far).

When the release mode is installed on my real device (the same problem happens even with production app from App Store), and when the app is opened from a background where it was for example 1,2 hours - my app freezes for several seconds (I can scroll my lists but Touchables are not working). Sometimes it freezes 5sec, sometimes 10sec... The freeze time is not constant.

For navigation, I use React Native Navigation. First of all, I thought that it can be a navigation problem - but I can navigate through tabs. So I can navigate through tabs, can scroll FlatLists in the tabs, but the list items are not Touchable - I can click them but onPress is not called.
And after several sec when the freeze is over - my app does all pending navigations. Namely it opens all screens which were tapped while the app was frozen...

Who had such kind of problem? And how can I solve this? Please help, I am stuck here a couple of days :(

React-Native: 0.59.10;
React: 16.8.3;

Thanks in advance

Comment: While you reopen your app, does that particular screen calls any API or perform any UI update? Though I've use 0.59.10 for past build, I don't face such issue. Try debugging and provide logs, maybe we can dive further from there.

Comment: @TommyLeong thanks for your message. Actually yes I call API, but no UI update. I even commented that API call to make sure the problem is not in it - and the same problem... App is frozen again

Comment: Can't tell exactly what's the issue without seeing your code. however the direction to troubleshoot should be API calling, you might want to have async&await for your API calling and update your UI using main thread. Try to check again what's running behind background beside the API calling, otherwise the UI should not be frozen.

Comment: @TommyLeong I have such problem only when the app is in the background for a long time only (for example 2 hours). If it is in the background for example 20 minutes, so when I open the app everything is ok there.

Comment: Never spotted or get complaint about such error. Does this happen to all iOS version or only iOS13 ?

Comment: @TommyLeong I noticed it on IOS13 and even on IOS12.1.4.

Comment: Interesting, I'll play around with my app to test although I doubt this would happen. Share us more update if you have further findings.

Comment: I've got the same problem but mine only happens when I'm streaming media, Android works fine but iOS doesn't register touches, scroll works. The problem occurs on ios 11.3 - 13.

Comment: I also have got same scenario can you tell me how you resolve this @David

Comment: Still so success @Vipul :(

Comment: I've got a similar problem. It is happening on iPhone XR (or maybe just certain iOS versions, I haven't fully tested them all). For me, it is freezing the entire app for 5-10 seconds. I'm also using RNN, but cannot change tabs, scroll a list, or tap anything. When it finally unfreezes, it is as if nothing happened. I can see, using AppState.addEventListener('change') that the app doesn't even get the app state of 'active' until after the freeze is complete. However, a simple setInterval(()=>console.log(),1000) reveals that code is able to run during the freeze period. Driving me crazy!

Comment: Same here. I'm getting crazy.

Comment: I had the same issue recently and it was caused by graphql subscription which failed to reconnect and stuck somewhere in JS code. Strangely when I added error handling the issue resolved. Something you might want to look into.

Comment: @David Hi, i also have same issue. Did you found any solution or root cause of this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(

Answer (score 3):

This exact thing happened to me, but my fix was so dumb, that there is a very high probability your problem might be related to something else. It took me a full day and part of the night to figure out however, so in the off chance it might help, here's what happened to me...

I have a function at the root of my app that initializes some things.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(init())
 }, []);
```

In some truly bizarre act I had added the following in my `init` function

```
setInterval(() => { dispatch(setTabsReady(true)) },0)
```

What I actually meant was

```
setTimeout(() => { dispatch(setTabsReady(true)) },0)
```

Astonishingly, this gem only seemed to affect things when I re-opened the app after switching to another.

It was a truly destructive thing that caused all manner of other strange behavior that I only realized in hindsight was related.

Comment: This was actually the cause of the freeze in my project... :) so thank you for that

Comment: No way! So glad it helped!

Comment: @MartinCarstens  I faced with the exactly same problem! Your day, saved days for us! Thanks a lot :)